# How can I create a sibling branch that includes all the commits from another branch into one node?

Tags: git, branch, commit, squash

I have a branch, mybranch, that has six commits and stems from commit C.  I would like to create a new branch, also based on commit C, that effectively includes all the commits from mybranch, squashed into one commit.  What's the easiest way to do this?

I need to do this due to the mantra of "squash before you git-push".  For the new branch, I don't want any mention of *mybranch* in the history pushed up to the remote server.  The reason I want to create a whole new branch used to push is because I'd like to keep all the commits in *mybranch* for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why only push squashed commits? That sounds crazy (and wrong).

But to answer your question:

```
git checkout -b newbranch # checkout new branch
git reset --soft C # move to commit C
git commit -m 'squashed commit'
```

Another possibility would be to use `rebase -i` to squash/fixup all commits into a single one:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git rebase -i C # now, replace every 'pick' with 'fixup'/'squash' except the first one
```

Also of interest is [`git merge --squash`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

```
git checkout -b newbranch C # create newbranch at commit C
git merge --squash mybranch
git commit -m 'squashed commit'
```

Comment: The last option seems the most clear and intuitively safe (merges never rewrite history) to me. Is there any reason to use either of the other two?

Comment: @Raphael: `git merge --squash` is not a "real" merge in the sense that it will connect to branches with a merge commit. It will create a "virtual" new branch with all changes of the original branch squashed into a single commit and then merge this new branch. If you decide to delete your original branch, all information about the single commits will be lost, your final history will only contain a single commit (which "replaced" all commits in the branch)

Comment: @knittl Isn't that true for any squash? That said, I did a `merge --squash` earlier today and found that the commit message of the new commit contained all commit messages.

Comment: @Raphael: messages yes, but the commits itself will be gone (dates, changes, …) all sqashed in a single commit

Comment: @knittl Of course. I guess I'm stumped. Can you please explain how the other two options are different in this regard? If I only merge the new branch (which, in all versions, has only the single squash commit) and not the original one, the history will be lost? Or is your point that it only looks safe while it isn't?

Comment: @Raphael: all three options result in the same history. I guess I only wanted to mention that `merge --squash` looks like a "real" merge, while it isn't and rewrites history the same as the other commands.